# Normalization of $f(x) = a(a-x)$ over $0 \leq x \leq a$

Tags: integration

So I tried to Normalize $f(x) = a(a-x)$ over interval $0 ≤ x ≤ a$ like this:

$[N^2\int_{0}^{a} f(x)^2 dx ]=1$

$= \ N^2\int_{0}^{a} (a^2(a-x)^2) dx \ =1$

$= \ N^2 a^2(-\int_{0}^{a} u^2 du) \ =1$

$= \ N^2 a^2[-\frac{u^3}{3}]_{0}^{a} \ = -N^2 a^2(0-\frac{a^3}{3})$

$= -N^2 a^2(-\frac{a^3}{3})=1$

$= \ N^2 \frac{a^5}{3}\ = 1$

so, $ N^2 = \frac{3}{a^5}$

hence, $ N = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{a^2\sqrt{a}}$

the normalized function thus becomes:

$ f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{a^2\sqrt{a}} (a(a-x))$

Please let me know if this is the correct way.

Comment: Yes, that is fine

Comment: @Falcon I took the constant $a^2$ out of the integral and substituted $u=-x+a$